# MySQL same query different criteria

Tags: mysql, datetime, subquery

I have a table with the following data:

```
+----------+---------------------+
| sesiones | fecha               |
+----------+---------------------+
|      350 | 2014-12-26 12:49:02 |
|      329 | 2014-12-26 12:48:01 |
|      320 | 2014-12-26 12:47:02 |
|      320 | 2014-12-26 12:46:01 |
|      328 | 2014-12-26 12:45:02 |
|      314 | 2014-12-26 12:44:01 |
|      318 | 2014-12-26 12:43:02 |
|      308 | 2014-12-26 12:42:01 |
|      326 | 2014-12-26 12:41:02 |
|      308 | 2014-12-26 12:40:01 |
```

I need to extract the "sesiones" in the same query, with the datetime of inserting data, another column with the "sesiones" the previous minute, but maintaining the datetime.

The output would be:

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+
| sesiones | minute | fecha               |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
|      350 |    329 | 2014-12-26 12:49:02 |
|      329 |    320 | 2014-12-26 12:48:01 |
|      320 |    320 | 2014-12-26 12:47:02 |
|      320 |    328 | 2014-12-26 12:46:01 |
|      328 |    314 | 2014-12-26 12:45:02 |
|      314 |    318 | 2014-12-26 12:44:01 |
|      318 |    308 | 2014-12-26 12:43:02 |
|      308 |    326 | 2014-12-26 12:42:01 |
|      326 |    308 | 2014-12-26 12:41:02 |
|      308 |    NULL| 2014-12-26 12:40:01 |
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(l.fecha,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), 
       l.sesiones, 
       ( 
              SELECT sesiones 
              FROM   bearsesiones 
              WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = Date_format(fecha - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) 'minute' 
FROM   bearsesiones l;
```

And the result:

```
| 2014-12-26 12:41                    |      326 |   NULL |
| 2014-12-26 12:42                    |      308 |   NULL |
| 2014-12-26 12:43                    |      318 |   NULL |
| 2014-12-26 12:44                    |      314 |   NULL |
| 2014-12-26 12:45                    |      328 |   NULL |
| 2014-12-26 12:46                    |      320 |   NULL |
| 2014-12-26 12:47                    |      320 |   NULL |
| 2014-12-26 12:48                    |      329 |   NULL |
| 2014-12-26 12:49                    |      350 |   NULL |
```

Edit, add field Auto_Increment:

```
|  46 | 2014-12-26 12:41                    |      326 |
|  48 | 2014-12-26 12:42                    |      308 |
|  50 | 2014-12-26 12:43                    |      318 |
|  52 | 2014-12-26 12:44                    |      314 |
|  54 | 2014-12-26 12:45                    |      328 |
|  56 | 2014-12-26 12:46                    |      320 |
|  58 | 2014-12-26 12:47                    |      320 |
|  60 | 2014-12-26 12:48                    |      329 |
|  62 | 2014-12-26 12:49                    |      350 |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a big problem while you have no primary key. Why don't you add autoincrement int ID field?

Comment: No problem, I can put a auto_increment. What would be the idea of adding an autoincrement field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT test1.sessiones, test2.sessiones AS
MINUTE , test1.fecha
FROM `test` AS test1
LEFT JOIN test AS test2 ON ( test1.id != test2.id
AND (
    test2.fecha
    BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( DATE_SUB( test1.fecha, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i" )
    AND DATE_FORMAT( test1.fecha, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i" ) )
)
ORDER BY test1.fecha DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, Good idea to add the id field.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(sesiones INT NOT NULL 
,fecha DATETIME NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(sesiones,fecha)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(350,'2014-12-26 12:49:02'),
(329,'2014-12-26 12:48:01'),
(320,'2014-12-26 12:47:02'),
(320,'2014-12-26 12:46:01'),
(328,'2014-12-26 12:45:02'),
(314,'2014-12-26 12:44:01'),
(318,'2014-12-26 12:43:02'),
(308,'2014-12-26 12:42:01'),
(326,'2014-12-26 12:41:02'),
(308,'2014-12-26 12:40:01');

SELECT a.sesiones
     , b.sesiones minute
     , a.fecha 
  FROM
     (
       SELECT x.*,COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.fecha <= x.fecha GROUP BY x.fecha
     ) a
  LEFT 
  JOIN
     (
       SELECT x.*,COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.fecha <= x.fecha GROUP BY x.fecha
     ) b 
    ON b.rank = a.rank-1
 ORDER 
    BY a.fecha DESC;

+----------+--------+---------------------+
| sesiones | minute | fecha               |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
|      350 |    329 | 2014-12-26 12:49:02 |
|      329 |    320 | 2014-12-26 12:48:01 |
|      320 |    320 | 2014-12-26 12:47:02 |
|      320 |    328 | 2014-12-26 12:46:01 |
|      328 |    314 | 2014-12-26 12:45:02 |
|      314 |    318 | 2014-12-26 12:44:01 |
|      318 |    308 | 2014-12-26 12:43:02 |
|      308 |    326 | 2014-12-26 12:42:01 |
|      326 |    308 | 2014-12-26 12:41:02 |
|      308 |   NULL | 2014-12-26 12:40:01 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
```